# checkinstall equivalent of `make install -C build`

Tags: make, checkinstall

What is the equivalent of:

`sudo make install -C build`

for `checkinstall`? Is it enough to:

```
cd build
sudo checkinstall
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `-C` option causes `make` to change to the specified directory before doing anything else; so in the absence of previous options to `make`,

```
cd build
...
```

is equivalent.